# IDS Visually same but actually are not

Tags: mysql

I faced a very wierd problem that in my db i set my id as primary key and it stores those ids too that are identical e.g:

```
+--------+
|   ID   |
+--------+
|  ABC94 |
|  ABC94 |
+--------+
```

When I deleted them then from phpmyadmin, then it generates following queries for deletion in which you can see one id contains `\r` which makes its unique but is not visible on select view. Kindly let me know how can i make sure when ids are getting saved then it should only take `ABC94` part and ignore any parts like `\r or \d or the like` . Thanks,

```
DELETE FROM `Db` WHERE `ID` = 'ABC94\r';
DELETE FROM `DB` WHERE `ID` = 'ABC94';
```

I tried following code but it gave me error due to `\` i guess cause it worked fine when i used `-` instead of `\`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( "ABC94\r",  "\", 1 )
```

Comment: how did you insert those records?

Comment: @JW. dump csv file to db, but i also moved after dumping the data to another table so i can apply the ignoring part while moving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is any possibility of extra white space, you must handle it either in your application code *before* insert, or trim it off with the RDBMS at INSERT time.

```
INSERT INTO `Db` (`ID`) VALUES (TRIM('input value'))
```

You cannot update your existing rows without key violations unless you devise a scheme of replacing whites pace with other printable characters.

For example, replace the carriage return characters with `x`, and they will still be unique:

```
/* Global replacement of carriage returns with 'x' */
UPDATE `Db` SET `ID` = REPLACE(`ID`, '\r', 'x')
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim

Your attempt with `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` was nearly valid, but you should have omitted the backslash and instead supplied the empty string `''`.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( 'ABC94\r',  '', 1 )
```

But using `TRIM()` as I have above is more reliable.  If at all possible, the best approach is to fix the source of the input data to avoid generating these in the first place.

Comment: Okay kindly let me know why `UPDATE table SET id = TRIM(  "id/r" ) WHERE id =  "Fall97\r"` is working fine but not 
`UPDATE table SET id = TRIM(  id ) WHERE id =  "Fall97\r"`

Comment: Do not supply a WHERE clause.  Running the update over all rows will trim each, but you cannot do it in place because you will get key violations. In your first example, you are updating to the literal string "id/r"  since it is quoted.

Comment: no i removed the id from my db, like `FALL97\r` is one id in the table but i am unable to update it by giving any db column if i give simple string the the trik works